# Replace attribute of XML parent node with values from child node

Tags: notepad++, regex, find-and-replace, xml

I have an xml file where I want to replace text in a parent node with some text from the child node. This is an example xml:

```
<output name="Element_152">
  <field name="NAME" key="true">Unit001</field>
  <field name="ITEM">CommStatus</field>
</output>
<output name="Element_153">
  <field name="NAME" key="true">Unit001</field>
  <field name="ITEM">UnitStatus</field>
</output>
```

I want to change the value of `<output name="Element_...">` attribute to be the value from `<field name="ITEM">`, so I will get:

```
<output name="CommStatus">
  <field name="NAME" key="true">Unit001</field>
  <field name="ITEM">CommStatus</field>
</output>
<output name="UnitStatus">
  <field name="NAME" key="true">Unit001</field>
  <field name="ITEM">UnitStatus</field>
</output>
```

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `(<output name=").+?(?=">(?:(?!</output>).)+<field name="ITEM">(.+?)</field>)`
- Replace with: `$1$2`
- **CHECK** *Match case*
- **CHECK** *Wrap around*
- **CHECK** *Regular expression*
- **CHECK** `. matches newline`
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

**Explanation:**

```
(<output name=")            # literally, group 1
.+?                         # 1 or more any character, not greedy
(?=                         # positive lookahead, make sure we have after:
    ">                          # literally
    (?:                         # non capture group, Tempered Greedy Token
        (?!</output>)               # negative lookahead, make sure we haven't <:output> after
        .                           # any character
    )+                          # end group, must appear 1 or more times
    <field name="ITEM">         # literally
    (.+?)                       # group 2, 1 or more any character, not greedy
    </field>                    # literally
)                           # end lookahead
```

**Replacement:**

```
$1      # content of group 1 (<output name=")
$2      # content of group 2 (the value of ITEM)
```

**Screenshot (before):**

[image]

**Screenshot (after):**

[image]

Comment: Thanks!! This works great.

Comment: @LironHallak: You're welcome, glad it helps.